# Added method to a concern, but getting undefined method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code in a rails concern:

```
module DestroyExclusion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(academy_id,product_id,category_id)
    if(category_id == nil)
      if exists?(:academy_id => academy_id, :product_id => product_id)
        where(:academy_id => academy_id, :product_id => product_id).first.destroy
      end
    elsif(product_id == nil)
      if exists?(:academy_id => academy_id, :category_id => category_id)
        where(:academy_id => academy_id, :category_id => category_id).first.destroy
      end
    end

  end
end
```

which is used in these classes:

```
class ExcludeProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DestroyExclusion
  belongs_to :academy
  belongs_to :product


end

class ExcludeCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DestroyExclusion
  belongs_to :academy
  belongs_to :category

end
```

However, when I try to call the method, I get an undefined method error. 
Any ideas why this may be? Here is an example of where I am calling the method:

```
  def destroy_exclusions
    category_record = Category.find(self.category_id)
    if !self.product_id.blank?
      academies = category_record.parent_academies
      academies.each do |academy|
        ExcludeProduct.destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(academy.id, self.product_id,nil)
      end
    else
      products = category_record.child_products
      products.each do |product|
        ExcludeProduct.destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(self.academy_id, product.id,nil)
      end
    end
  end
```

here is an example of the error I am getting (from running my specs):

```
 1) AcademyCategoryProduct successfully destroys exclusions
     Failure/Error: category_product.destroy_exclusions
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion' for #<Class:0x007fc532c0ae50>
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
     # ./app/models/academy_category_product.rb:13:in `block in destroy_exclusions'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
     # ./app/models/academy_category_product.rb:12:in `destroy_exclusions'
     # ./spec/models/academy_category_product_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The specfile in question:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe AcademyCategoryProduct do

  let(:product) { FactoryGirl.create(:academy_product) }
  let(:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }
  let(:subcategory) {FactoryGirl.create(:category, :parent_id => category.id)}
  let(:academy) { FactoryGirl.create(:academy) }
  let(:category_product) { FactoryGirl.create(:academy_category_product, :category_id => subcategory.id, :product_id => product.id, :academy_id => nil) }
  let(:academy_category) { FactoryGirl.create(:academy_category_product, :category_id => category.id, :academy_id => academy.id, :product_id => nil ) }
  let(:exclude_product) { FactoryGirl.create(:exclude_product, :product_id => product.id, :academy_id => academy.id) }
  let(:exclude_category) { FactoryGirl.create(:exclude_category, :category_id => subcategory.id, :academy_id => academy.id) }

  before(:each) do
    category.reload
    academy.reload
    exclude_category.reload
    exclude_product.reload
    category_product.reload
    academy_category.reload
    exclude_product.reload
  end

  it "successfully destroys exclusions" do
    category_product.destroy_exclusions
    expect(ExcludeProduct.first).to eql(nil)
  end

  it "successfully destroys category exclusions" do
    academy_category.destroy_category_exclusions
    expect(ExcludeCategory.first).to eql(nil)
  end
end
```

EDIT - I made the following changes to my concern as per goddamnyouryan's answer:

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module DestroyExclusion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do

    def self.destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(academy_id,product_id,category_id)
      if(category_id == nil)
        if exists?(:academy_id => academy_id, :product_id => product_id)
          where(:academy_id => academy_id, :product_id => product_id).first.destroy
        end
      elsif(product_id == nil)
        if exists?(:academy_id => academy_id, :category_id => category_id)
          where(:academy_id => academy_id, :category_id => category_id).first.destroy
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I get the following error:

```
Users/karuna/Documents/Projects/catalog/app/models/concerns/destroy_exclusion.rb:5:in `<module:DestroyExclusion>': undefined method `class_methods' for DestroyExclusion:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: @BradWerth thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my question with one of the specs I am using and its failure message

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Rails 4 (and Rails 5), if you want to define a class method inside your concern, then you have to just define that method inside a:

```
module ClassMethods
 . . . 
end
```

which is what you are looking for. The code contained within this `module ClassMethods` block will be added to the Class itself.

So, your modified concern code should look like this:

```
module DestroyExclusion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(academy_id,product_id,category_id)
      if(category_id == nil)
        if exists?(:academy_id => academy_id, :product_id => product_id)
          where(:academy_id => academy_id, :product_id => product_id).first.destroy
        end
      elsif(product_id == nil)
        if exists?(:academy_id => academy_id, :category_id => category_id)
          where(:academy_id => academy_id, :category_id => category_id).first.destroy
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

[This tutorial](https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-code-concerns-in-active-record-models) has a simple and nice explanation about concerns in Rails 4!

Comment: This is wrong, even if it works. Instead of using `module ClassMethods` you should use `class_methods` if you decide to use ActiveSupport. @goddamnyouryan gave correct answer.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html - here you can see both examples with and without ActiveSupport.

Comment: Rails is literally the worst. The worst.

Answer (score 9):

You need to nest these methods in a `class_methods do` block.  See the [documentation for ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-class_methods)

Something like:

```
module DestroyExclusion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(etc)
      # omitted
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried added a class_methods do block, but I get an undefined method error for "class_methods" - I've updated the question with my changes

Comment: @Karuna-bdc what version of rails are you running?

Comment: Rails 4, @K M Rakibul Islam's answer worked. Thanks for your help too though

Comment: `class_methods` available only for rails 4.2.0 and above

Comment: @goddamnyouryan, no it cannot have `self` on the definition or it will not work.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to define class methods inside your concern:

For Rails version < 4.2.0,

```
module DestroyExclusion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(etc)
      # some code
    end
  end
end
```

For Rails version >= 4.2.0

```
module DestroyExclusion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(etc)
      # some code
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby way of doing thing

```
module DestroyExclusion
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def destroy_exclusion_on_category_deletion(etc)
      # some code
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and K M Rakibul Islam's answer was 99% right, but I had to include the following method in my model concern to get ClassMethod working for me.

```
def self.included(base)
   base.extend(ClassMethods)
end
```

Thanks @K-M-Rakibul-Islam, this was a big headache for me!

Comment: Yes, this is the classic way without `ActiveSupport` and it works until you get complex dependencies, which require you to start using `ActiveSupport`.